# Solving Differential Functional Equation $f(2x)=2f(x)f'(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Find all functions satisfying $f(2x)=2f'(x)f(x)$
Under given condition, can't we find explicit solutions?

Comment: At least $e^{x/2}$ satisfies it, but I have no idea how to get there analytically.

Comment: Try $g(x) = f(x)^2$, solve $g'(x) = f(2x)$

Comment: Also $f(x)=x$ works...

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is also a solution

Comment: Why does this question have this many upvotes?

Comment: also $\sin (x)$ make the work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If one restrict oneself to functions which admit a power series expansion at $x = 0$,
following is the list of solutions I found:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,             & f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 0,\\
k \sin(x/k),   & f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1, f'''(0) < 0\\
x,             & f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1, f'''(0) = 0\\
k \sinh(x/k),  & f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1, f'''(0) > 0\\
k \exp(x/2k),  & f(0) \ne 0, f'(0) = \frac12\\
\end{cases}$$

where $k$ is a non-zero constant.

Let $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots$. In terms of $a_n$, the function equation becomes:

$$\begin{align}
a_0     &= 2 ( a_1 a_0 )\tag{*0}\\
2\,a_1  &= 2 ( 2 a_2 a_0 + a_1 a_1 )\tag{*1}\\
2^2 a_2 &= 2 ( 3 a_3 a_0 + 2 a_2 a_1 + a_1 a_2 )\\
2^3 a_3 &= 2 ( 4 a_4 a_0 + 3 a_3 a_1 + 2 a_2 a_2 + a_1 a_3 )\\
2^4 a_4 &= 2 ( 5 a_5 a_0 + 4 a_4 a_1 + 3 a_3 a_2 + 2 a_2 a_3 + a_1 a_4)\\
2^5 a_5 &= 2 ( 6 a_6 a_0 + 5 a_5 a_1 + 4 a_4 a_2 + 3 a_3 a_3 + 2 a_2 a_4 + a_1 a_5 )\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align}$$

The first thing we notice is $(*0)$ implies:

$$a_0 (1 - 2a_1) = 0 \implies a_0 = 0 \quad\text{ or }\quad a_1 = \frac12$$

If $a_0 = 0$, then $(*1)$ implies $a_1 = 0$ or $1$. It is easy to see $a_1 = 0$ will lead us to $f(x) \equiv 0$. So let us assume $a_1 = 1$. The set of equations become:
$$\begin{align}
( 2^1 - 3 ) a_2 &= 0\\
( 2^2 - 4 ) a_3 &= 2 a_2 a_2 \iff 0 = 0 \text{ ( i.e. } a_3\;\text{ is arbitrary )}\\
( 2^3 - 5 ) a_4 &= 3 a_3 a_2 + 2 a_2 a_3\\
( 2^4 - 6 ) a_5 &= 4 a_4 a_2 + 3 a_3 a_3 + 2 a_2 a_4\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align}$$
It is then easy to see:

1. $a_n = 0$ for all even $n$.
2. $a_3$ is arbitrary.
3. once $a_3$ is fixed, $a_n$ is recursively fixed for all odd $n > 3$.

Depends on the sign of $a_3$, it leads us to solutions of the form $k \sin(x/k), x $ or k sinh(x/k)$.

If $a_0 \ne 0$, then $a_1 = \frac12$ and the set of equations becomes:

$$\begin{align}
2 a_2 a_0 &= 2^0\,a_1   - ( a_1 a_1 )\tag{*1}\\
3 a_3 a_0 &= 2^1 a_2  - ( 2 a_2 a_1 + a_1 a_2 )\\
4 a_4 a_0 &= 2^2 a_3 - ( 3 a_3 a_1 + 2 a_2 a_2 + a_1 a_3 )\\
5 a_5 a_0 &= 2^3 a_4  - ( 4 a_4 a_1 + 3 a_3 a_2 + 2 a_2 a_3 + a_1 a_4)\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align}$$
It is easy to see these will recursively fix the values of $a_n$ for all $n > 1$. This lead us to the $k \exp(x/2k)$ solution.

Comment: +1 Nice! I like the solutions with scaled sines and hyperbolic sines. Should have spotted those.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oops, thanks for pointing out the typos.

Comment: +1: *Of course* the site doesn't let me know that you posted this, so that when I post my answer, your more complete answer pops up and tells me it has been up for 26 minutes. /sigh/

Comment: @CameronBuie, same thing happen to me when I compose my answer. Only after I finish it, the site let me know Jyrki has performed the analysis using power series...

Comment: @CameronBuie: This happens every now and then and cannot be helped. When you are composing a longish answer, the probability of it happening goes up. I first posted a solution covering the case $a_1\neq0$ only. You may or may not have seen that - nobody cares. I even indicated that I may not be able to solve the other case to make doubly sure that the question is still open. Then I edited my solution to include some of my calculations. The messages about updates to other answers are not as noticable as the messages about new answers, so my update was "in the dark" for both of you.

Comment: (cont'd) Sorry about that. Anyway, Achille managed to identify the resulting power series, and deserves more credit. There's no doubt that Cameron arrived at his solution independently, so I would upvote it, if it were undeleted :-)

Comment: @Jyrki: Achille's answer is complete for functions given by a power series, so I just deleted mine in favor of his. Not worried about the "lost" upvotes, but I do bemoan the waste of time.

Comment: How does one discover the closed formula $k \sin(x/k)$ from the coefficents?

Answer (score 6):

Assume that a solution $f(x)$ is analytic in some neighborhood of $x=0$ so that it can be represented as a converging power series
$$
f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots.
$$

If we assume that $a_0=f(0)\neq0$, then, by equating the power series representing the two sides of the given equation, we see that the remaining coefficients are uniquely determined. Comparing the coefficient of $x^\ell$ on both sides gives a linear equation for $a_{\ell+1}$ with a non-zero coefficient.

So if an analytic solution with a fixed value $f(0)=k\neq0$ exists, it is unique. An ansatz of the form
$$f(x)=ke^{\lambda x}$$
as in rajb245's answer works, iff $\lambda=1/2k$. Therefore we have a one-parameter family of solutions
$$
f(x)=f_k(x)=ke^{x/2k}.
$$
If $a_0=0$ things become messy, as the proffered solutions $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\sin x$ prove. Unless I made a mistake, we get that then $a_1=0$ or $a_1=1$. In the latter case I got that we necessarily have $a_2=0$, but $a_3$ can be arbitrary, which goes together with the known solutions. Probably this approach can be taken further (most likely by somebody else)...

---

Again assuming analyticity, and taking advantage of mezhang's observation that the r.h.s. is the derivative of $f(x)^2$ we get by differentiating the given equation $k$ times we get the equations
$$
2^kf^{(k)}(2x)=D^{k+1}\left[f(x)^2\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}{k+1\choose i} f^{(i)}(x)f^{(k+1-i)}(x).
$$
Plugging in $x=0$ gives then the system of equations
$$
2^kf^{(k)}(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}{k+1\choose i} f^{(i)}(0)f^{(k+1-i)}(0)
$$
that holds for all $k$. As $f^{(k)}(0)=k!a_k$ we get
$$
2^k k! a_k=(k+1)!\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_ia_{k+1-i}.
$$

Assuming (see above) $a_0=0,a_1=1$ this gives us
$$
2^kk!a_k=(k+1)!\left(2a_k+\sum_{i=2}^{k-1}a_ia_{k+1-i}\right).
$$
With $k=2$ we get $a_2=0$ (confirming my hand calculations). With $k=3$ we get a tautology $48a_3=48a_3$ that does, indeed, leave the value of $a_3$ undetermined.
For $k>3$ we have $2^kk!>2(k+1)!$, so we get an equation recursively determining
$a_k$. Observe that a straightforward induction proves (after this start) that $a_k=0$ whenever $k$ is even. Thus the resulting function $f(x)$ is odd, and uniquely determined by the value of $a_3$. I don't know, if the solution is always an elementary function.

In the case $a_0=a_1=0$ the term $(k+1)!(a_1a_k+a_ka_1)=2(k+1)!a_ka_1$ is not there on the r.h.s., so we get the equations
$$
2^kk!a_k=(k+1)!\left(\sum_{i=2}^{k-1}a_ia_{k+1-i}\right)
$$
for all $k$. Again we recursively see that this system has only the trivial solution $a_k=0$ for all $k$.

Comment: So barring a mistake the given equation has two one-parameter families of analytic solutions. I don't know the closed form of the other family $f(x)=x+a_3x^3+\cdots?$

Comment: But Achille Hui figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the ansatz $f(x)=e^{kx}$, then $f(2x)=e^{2kx}=f(x)^2$, $f'(x)=ke^{kx}=kf(x)$. The equation is

$$
f^2(x)=2 (k f(x))f(x)
$$

$$
f^2(x)=2k f^2(x)\Rightarrow k=1/2
$$

Substituting that $k$ back in gives $f(x)=e^{x/2}$

Of course this doesn't seem to get at all the solutions...it seems $f(x)=x$ is another solution, but this is a start on the exponential solutions. You can look for power solutions using a similar method...

**Edit**

Users have mentioned the following are all solutions

\begin{align}
f(x)&=0 \\
f(x) &= x\\
f(x) &= \sin(x)\\
f(x) &= e^{x/2}
\end{align}

I don't know the technique to get the general solution to these types of equations.  I'm not even sure what to google.  "Functional differential equation" is moderately helpful...

Comment: This isn't the only solution, though. As Coffee_Table points out above, $f(x)=x$ works just fine.

Comment: Also Clark just noted that $sin(x)$ is a solution

Comment: Suppose the *ansatz* (whatever that means) $f(x)=k\cdot 0$, then $\cdots$ and it follows that $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Yes, the trivial solution $f(x)=0$ works as well.  As for ansatz: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz