# Are there any other functions which satisfy $\frac d{dx}f^2(x)=f(2x)$ other than $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f(x)=x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, functional-equations

I have been practicing functional equations recently and decided to do a functional equation that involves derivatives:$$\text{Find all functions }\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\text{ such that }\dfrac d{dx}f^2(x)=f(2x)$$Now a solution that can be found right away is the identity function $I(x)=x$, and the other solution I was able to find was $\sin(x)$ (which is done through the sine addition formula):$$\dfrac d{dx}\sin^2(x)=\dfrac d{dx}\sin(x)\sin(x)\\=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(x)\\=2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$$however I have been unable to find other solutions, so my question is: Are there other solutions to the functional equation $\dfrac d{dx}f^2(x)$, or are $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$ the only solutions?

Comment: $\sinh x$ is another obvious solution, and there must be more.

Comment: Another obvious solution is $ f(x)=0$.

Comment: Further to that, another solution is $e^{\frac{1}{2}*x}$ and $-e^{\frac{-1}{2}*x}$

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{1}{2\beta} e^{\beta x}, \beta \ne 0$ is another family of solution.

Comment: Try a series expansion about 0? I get $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @preferred_anon I used the Maclaren series but more work to do!!

Comment: Thinking about the chain rule/implicit differentiation, note that, $2f(x)f'(x)=\dfrac d{dx}f^2(x)=f(2x),$ so this  can be rearranged as $f'(x) = \frac{f(2x)}{2f(x)}.$ I don't know if this is useful... But maybe we could then try integrating the RHS with IBP or something..?

Comment: @achillehui The problem isn't linear, but is it possible to derive the $\sin$ and $\sinh$ solutions from this?

Comment: @whpowell96  Nope, you can't derive sin or sinh from $\frac1{2\beta}e^{\beta x}$. Instead, you can assume $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ has a taylor expansion around $x = 0$. Substitute that into $(f^2)'(x) = f(2x)$ and match the coefficients. If $a_0 \ne 0$, you will get $\frac{1}{2\beta}e^{\beta x}$. If $a_0 = 0$ but $a_1 \ne 0$, you will get $a_1 = 1$, all $a_{2k} = 0$ and everything else depends on $a_3$, this will give you solution $\frac1{\beta}\sin\beta x$ or $\frac{1}{\beta}\sinh(\beta x)$ depends on sign of $a_3^2$.

Comment: oops, should be sign of $a_3$. As a side note, the solution $f(x) = x$ can be viewed as a special case by taking limit $\beta \to 0$.

Comment: @achillehui I played around with it a bit and you can take a linear combination of $\frac{1}{2\beta}e^{\beta x}$ solutions and derive that $\beta_1 = -\beta_2$ which yields sin and sinh.

Comment: You can also paste together solutions at the origin, for example, $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = \sin(x)$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Time flies. I didn't remember I have actually [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/368410) essentially same question ten years ago...